# How can I detect when a gameobject enters the area of another gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that make a gameobject to move in some height for example at 200.
On a terrain i have another gameobject. I want that when the first gameobject that move when he start entering the other gameobject area do something.

Like

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
       if (other.gameObject.name == "Base")
      {

      } 
    }
```

But this is not working since there is no physical collide between the transform and the "Base". transform is at height 200.

I also tried to use Raycast hit.
In the top of the script i added:

```
Collider col;
```

Then in the Update

```
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (col.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0F))
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit !");
    }
```

But again the transform is in the air.
The idea is to do something once the transform start entering the Base area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple way to achieve that:

- Make a child game object of the base, with only a `Box Collider` component (`isTrigger` set to `true`)
- Extend the collider of this game object on the y axis (think of it as a pillar), like this:
  [image]
- Attach a script to your moving game object, with this code:

  ```
  using UnityEngine;

  public class CheckBaseCollider : MonoBehaviour {
      public GameObject baseCollider;

      private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
          if (other.gameObject == baseCollider) {
              Debug.Log("Entered");
          }
      }
  }
  ```

And you're good to go.