# Why the gameobject is not finish the rotation when entering another gameobject area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my previous question: [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801078/how-can-i-detect-when-a-gameobject-that-move-in-a-some-height-is-entering-anothe)

The answer there was right and working.
Once the gameobject start entering the other gameobject area it does something.

This is the script i attached to the moving gameobject that check for colliding:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckBaseCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject baseCollider;
    public GameObject objectToRotate;
    public bool rotate = false;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == baseCollider)
        {
            Debug.Log("Entered");

            rotate = true;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (rotate == true)
        {
            var str = Mathf.Min(.5f * Time.deltaTime, 1);
            objectToRotate.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.identity, str);
        }
    }
}
```

I have two gameobjects. One is the Base(A Cube it's variable is baseTarget).
The "Base" is on the terrain.
I want that when the other GameObject that move start entering the "Base" it will also start to rotate. But for some reason the rotation start then stop and then after some seconds resume and finish. Not sure why it stop.

This is the script of the moving gameobject also attached to the moving gameobject:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ControlShip : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float maxVel = 30; // cruise speed
    public float startVel = 5; // speed at the starting point
    public float stopVel = 0.5f; // speed at the destination
    public float accDistance = 20; // acceleration/deceleration distance
    public float factor = 0.25f; // max inclination
    public float turnSpeed = 0.8f; // speed to turn/bank in the target direction
    Vector3 lastPos; // used to calculate current velocity
    Transform baseTarget;
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        baseTarget = GameObject.Find("Base").transform;
        lastPos = transform.position;
        StartCoroutine(Fly()); // demo routine
    }
    // calculate bank/turn rotation at Update
    void Update()
    {
        // calculate the displacement since last frame:
        Vector3 dir = transform.position - lastPos;
        lastPos = transform.position; // update lastPos
        float dist = dir.magnitude;
        if (dist > 0.001f)
        { // if moved at least 0.001...
            dir /= dist; // normalize dir...
            float vel = dist / Time.deltaTime; // and calculate current velocity
                                               // bank in the direction of movement according to velocity
            Quaternion bankRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir + factor * Vector3.down * vel / maxVel);

            Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, bankRot, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime).eulerAngles;
            rotation.x = 0;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation);
        }           
    }

    bool flying = false; // shows when FlyTo is running
                         // coroutine that moves to the specified point:
    IEnumerator FlyTo(Vector3 targetPos)
    {
        flying = true; // flying is true while moving to the target
        Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
        targetPos.y = startPos.y;
        Vector3 dir = targetPos - startPos;
        float distTotal = dir.magnitude;
        dir /= distTotal; // normalize vector dir
                          // calculate accDist even for short distances
        float accDist = Mathf.Min(accDistance, distTotal / 2);
        do
        {
            float dist1 = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, startPos);
            float dist2 = distTotal - dist1;
            float speed = maxVel; // assume cruise speed
            if (dist1 < accDist)
            { // but if in acceleration range...
              // accelerate from startVel to maxVel
                speed = Mathf.Lerp(startVel, maxVel, dist1 / accDist);
            }
            else
            if (dist2 < accDist)
            { // or in deceleration range...
              // fall from maxVel to stopVel
                speed = Mathf.Lerp(stopVel, maxVel, dist2 / accDist);
            }
            // move according to current speed:

            Vector3 pos = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            //pos.y = lastPos.y;
            transform.position = pos;
            yield return 0; // let Unity breathe till next frame
        } while (transform.position != targetPos); // finish when target reached
        flying = false; // shows that flight has finished
    }
    // example routine: fly to 3 different points in sequence
    IEnumerator Fly()
    {
        Vector3 p0 = baseTarget.position;

        while (true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FlyTo(p0));
            while (flying)
            {
                yield return 0;
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want that when the moving object enter to the other object area to start rotating and to end the rotation before he stop moving(flying). But the idea is that it will complete the rotation while entering the other gameobject area.  But it's rotating a bit then wait and then after some seconds continue the rotation.

Comment: I think your problem is that both of these scripts are performing a rotation maneuver and they're conflicting with each other.